# Curl stopped working in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I have an application that runs continuously on Google App Engine and tests our main product. I don't change it that often but at 4am last night (Tuesday morning) the curl method stopped working - I know this from checking my application's logs.

I initially thought it was due to our product's api being down, but after looking into it more it seems the requests are returning a status code of 0 and are not even reaching the api servers.

The error from the curl request is:
(I also have the php.ini file correctly setup.)

```
Couldn't resolve host '{our_api_url}'
```

I have thoroughly checked with our developers and it really isn't anything to do with our main product, our api is working fine and I can't find any issue with my code.

Here is the curl code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_url = {api_url};
$headers = array('Authorization: Basic {encoded_credentials});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$debug = curl_getinfo($ch);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($out, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($out, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: host resolution usually refers to DNS. To address your question further  you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: What more details would you like to know?

Comment: `our_api_url` (if you can share that publicly, or a redacted version of it), stack trace, the output of running `host our_api_url` in the console of the php server which is running that program. Also if I'm not mistaken (it's been a while since I wrote any PHP), you can get error details from a failed curl call.

Comment: Yes that error message I posted is the error from the failed curl call

Comment: I have this issue too, This is not a PHP problem but something related to GAE. @user5331188 could you please share your php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 9.11.16

Google fixed this problem.

Comment: Ah yes, I noticed it suddenly started working! Thanks